# Specify relationship verbs in Django at runtime?

Tags: python, sql, database, django, model

How do you identify model relationship verbs in Django?

So, lets say I have a model `Movie`, and want fields for `Director` and `Writer`.  I don't want to have two distinct tables for these roles, like this:

[image: entity relationship diagram, incorrect]

...because it violates database best practices (normal forms, etc.), and doesn't keep things DRY.  Instead I want a single `Person` model, via a `ManyToMany` relationship with `Movie`, like this:

[image: entity relationship diagram, correct]

How do I allow these verbs, marked in the diamonds, to be specified at runtime?

For example, in the Django Admin, `Movie` should have a `Person` field, with some place to enter a `Role`, e.g. `written by` or `directed by`.  I don't want to have fields in `Movie` for each possible role: I don't want a `director` or `writer` or `animal_trainer` field, for example.  There might be hundreds... some of them duplicates.

In Rails, I'd just make a join table with an extra field `Role`, but I assume Django has a better way.

I'm sure this is documented somewhere in the Django docs, or maybe just in general SQL docs somewhere, but I guess I don't know the correct search terms to Google.  A link to relevant docs would be sufficient, if they exist.  Thanks!

Comment: Im pretty sure you would need a 3rd table to tell relationships between person and movie eg("Director","Actor","Author","Key Grip", etc) `Table("movie_role",["movie","person","role"])` type thing

Comment: you mean like a join table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option in (for this context) is simply having 2 models, Movie and person, and having 2 foreign keys in the Movie table, one for writer, one for director, since every movie will have both of those fields, e.g.

```
def Person(models.Model):
    ...
def Movie(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='movies_written')
    director = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='movies_directed')
    ...
```

**EDIT**

With your change in question, I believe the best answer to this is from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

```
def Person(models.Model):
    ...

def Movie(models.Model):
    ...
    workers = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='WorkedOn')

# model in case you want to specify anything specific for roles for every person
def Role(models.Model):
    ...

# can have extra fields, e.g. dates worked, pay, etc.
def WorkedOn(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    movie = models.ForeignKey('Movie')
    role = models.ForeignKey('Role')
    ...
```

Comment: Yep, I think this is it, as simple as it seems.  In particular: `related_name` was the attribute which fills the gap here, I think, and which I didn't know to Google.  Thanks!

Comment: Wondering, though... with `related_name` available, why then is ManyToMany even necessary?

Comment: Now that I look at it again, though, I'm not quite sure, although this gets close.  The problem is this will lead to a LOT of fields in `Movie`, some of which are hypothetical, or unique to a particular `Movie`.  For example, this would mean every `Movie` would need a field `key_grip` and `assistant_key_grip` and `animal_trainer`.  And what if there are two `assistant_key_grip`s?  Another field.  I'd really like a more flexible solution, which would allow the user to enter the verb, or role, of the `Person` to be entered at runtime.  I'll edit my question.

Comment: After looking at this again, I think this is the right answer again.  :)  For the more complex stuff, there probably should be some abstract base classes and/or inheritance.  Thanks.